# javascript own color for div

Tags: javascript

My problem is that i have sticky notes that i create, but everytime i create a new one i can change the color on the new one, but i can change the color on the first note which then changes the color on them all. 
I want to pick a color for each of them so they can have like a unique color for themself. 
This is my Codepen:
https://codepen.io/Qbinx/pen/OmObRg?editors=1010
This happens when i create a new Note:

```
createNote = function(){
        var stickerEl = document.createElement('div'),
            barEl = document.createElement('div'),
            color = document.createElement('button'),
            colorIcon = document.createElement('i'),
            deleteBtn = document.createElement('button'),
            deleteBtnIcon = document.createElement('i'),
            moveIcon = document.createElement('i'),
            colorEl = document.createElement('input'),
            textareaEl = document.createElement('textarea');

        var transformCSSValue = "translateX(" + Math.random() * 800 + "px) translateY(" + Math.random() * 400 + "px)";

        stickerEl.style.transform = transformCSSValue; 

        barEl.classList.add('bar');
        stickerEl.classList.add('sticker');
        color.classList.add('color');
        deleteBtn.classList.add('deleteBtn');
        deleteBtnIcon.classList.add('ion-android-delete');
        colorIcon.classList.add('ion-android-color-palette');
        stickerEl.id = "rect" + totalNotes++;

        colorEl.classList.add('jscolor');
        colorEl.onchange = function(){update(this.jscolor)};
        colorEl.value = "cc66ff";

        stickerEl.append(barEl);
        stickerEl.append(color);
        stickerEl.append(deleteBtn);
        stickerEl.append(colorEl);
        stickerEl.appendChild(textareaEl); 
        color.append(colorIcon);
        deleteBtn.append(deleteBtnIcon);
        barEl.append(moveIcon);

        stickerEl.addEventListener('mousedown', onDragStart, false);

        document.body.appendChild(stickerEl);

    };
```

So what can i do to change the color of each of the notes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i pass to describe what i did to make it work.

- Put the code of jscolor.js up, because the complete solution has a dependence on that library.
- Initialize the library of jscolor in line 1850.
- Modify the createNote method, from this

  ```
  colorEl.classList.add('jscolor');
  colorEl.onchange = function(){update(this.jscolor)};
  colorEl.value = "cc66ff";
  ```

  To this

  ```
  colorEl.classList.add('jscolor');
  colorEl.value = "cc66ff";  
  var picker = new jscolor(colorEl);
  colorEl.onchange = function(){ update(colorEl.value)};
  ```

  This was made specifically to create the picker when create a new note.
- Modify the update method from this

  ```
  var colorCall = document.getElementsByClassName('sticker');
  var NotesCall = Array.prototype.filter.call(colorCall, 
  function(colorCall){
  return colorCall.style.backgroundColor =  "#" + jscolor;
  ```

  To this

  ```
  var colorCall = document.querySelectorAll(".jscolor-active");
  var NotesCall = Array.prototype.filter.call(colorCall,                 
  function(colorCall){
    return colorCall.parentNode.style.backgroundColor =  "#" + jscolor;
  });
  ```

  Changing basically the way it selects the item to be color changed.

Here is the codepen of that: https://codepen.io/jukanjavir/pen/wdyVGR

Hope it helps.